# angular-cli ng fails to create new project: Err No matching version found for @angular/cli@~0.0.0

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am new to angular, it was working initially and I created some sample projects, real fun!! Then I tried to clone a project and ran `npm install` and since I have not been able to run (`serve`) any previous projects or create new ones.

When creating new projects it throws the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@~0.0.0.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'hello-world'
npm ERR! notarget
```

I installed angular using `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`

Checked the version `ng --version` shows

```
Angular CLI: local (v0.0.0, branch: master)
Node: 12.13.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    <error>
@angular-devkit/core         <error>
@angular-devkit/schematics   <error>
@schematics/angular          <error>
@schematics/update           <error>
```

I've tried various suggestion I found

- uninstalling module
- clearing cache (--force) etc
- or updating version as suggested here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli#updating-angular-cli

Nothing has worked so far

I must have missed something … as the previous projects show the correct version of angular/cli when I ran `ng --version`

```
Angular CLI: local (v0.0.0, branch: master)
Node: 12.13.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.19
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.19
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.19
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.19
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.19
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.19
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.19
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.19
@schematics/angular               8.3.19
@schematics/update                0.803.19
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have Nodejs already installed on my machine. Here are the steps that I followed to attempt to reproduce:

1. Installed the Angular CLI by running 
   `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`
2. Checked Angular version by running `ng --version` which gave me the following:

   ```
   Angular CLI: 8.3.19 
   Node: 10.15.3
   ```
3. Cloned an example Angular project. I used this one: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted
4. In the new directory, I ran the following:

   ```
   npm install && npm update
   ```

And finally, I ran `ng serve` which successfully initiated my web application and hosted on `localhost:4200`

I would suggest removing the currently installed Angular package on your machine (global location and local location). Then reinstall Angular and try once more.

Comment: I can run this no problem and it serves it too. But the underlying problem of failing to create new project still remains...

Comment: Test the solution before typing

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you don't have the old CLI package installed, run:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Then run:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Comment: I tried that before...the commands run normally but as check the version with `ng --version` it still outputs the same info as above and packages with `<error>` as versions.